# How to get current row HTML Table cell element?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a angular material table. If I click one row, i wanted to fetch the HTMLTableCellElement of the **selected row** . I tried using viewChild but the problem is i am getting whole table html element.
Expected output [image: HTMLTableCellElement output]
Below is my code. Please Help me to acheive this scenario !
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-nym2vx?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Please include a minimum reproducible example in the question, instead of in a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes you can make from the sample you have provided.

Change : 1 (in .html side)
Pass event via the function : viewhtmlData()

```
  <a href="javascript:;" (click)="viewhtmlData()">{{ element.name }}</a>
```

to

```
 <a href="javascript:;" (click)="viewhtmlData(element)">{{ element.name }}</a>
```

Change 2:(in .ts side)
Pass the element through the function

```
// This function will show entire table contents
  viewhtmlData() {
    console.log('Selected Row HtML data',this.table);
  }
```

to

```
// The element data from  .html is passed through the function
  viewhtmlData($event) {
    console.log('Selected Row HtML data',$event);
    this.selectedElement =$event;
    var Row = document.getElementById($event.position)  as HTMLTableCellElement;    
    this.selectedCellHtml = Row;
   
    console.log('Selected Row HtML data',this.selectedCellHtml);
    
  }
```

For further reference, you can go through the below sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-gpybg5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I want the htmlcontent just like                                                            
 HTMLTableCellElement {tagName: "td", attributes: {…}, innerHTML: "1", nodeType: 1…}
attributes: Object
class: "mat-cell cdk-column-position mat-column-position"
id: "1"
mat-cell: ""
role: "gridcell"
_ngcontent-imd-c1: ""
__proto__: Object
innerHTML: "1"
nodeType: 1
tagName: "td"

Comment: @Sanjana, please check and confirm

Comment: edited the viewhtmlData(){}

Answer (score 2):

In your example when you click on the a tag you can also send that tag to your function:

```
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" id="{{ element.position }}">
    <a href="javascript:;" (click)="viewhtmlData($event.target)">{{
      element.name
    }}</a>
  </mat-cell>
```

Then, inside your function you can get the parent of that a tag which is the mat-cell containing it, like so:

```
  viewhtmlData(aTag: HTMLElement) {
    console.log('Selected Row HtML data', aTag.parentElement);
  }

  <!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->
  <mat-cell _ngcontent-c69="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name" role="gridcell" id="3">
    <a _ngcontent-c69="" href="javascript:;">Lithium</a>
  </mat-cell>
```